# Replacing with Null in ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-10.3

In ArcGIS 10.3 Desktop, how do you replace field values with Null using the Field Calculator without selecting the rows first?

I'm able to select the rows that I want and calculate using the Field Calculator, e.g. `field_value = Null`. However, if I try to use `replace()` I get errors.

```
field_value = replace([field_value],0,Null)
```

Error:

> Invalid use of Null:'replace'

Comment: What parser are you using?  Python or VB?

Comment: replace is for strings in Python and in VB. In Python there's no type Null, therefore None exists. In VB it is Nothing, I think. And the field should be nullable (Field Properties: Allow NULL Values).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, with Python activated. Make sure, your field is nullable.

```
None if !foo! == "0" else !foo!
```

where !foo! is your field name, inside the exclamation marks.